# Virtualbox cannot attach any usb device to guest on desktop

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I'm trying to attach my arduino to a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM in virtual box. And for some reason it won't attach at all. Extension Pack is installed.

I tested if a normal usbstick would work: nope, I tested usb 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 guest settings, all nope. I tried a filter, still nope. I tried usb 2.0 and 3.0 on the physical machine, still nope.

When I select the device to attach from my VM the first attempt it dissapears from the host devices (But doesn't show up on the guest), on the second attempt (or the first manual attempt with a filter) I get:

```
Failed to attach the USB device Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
Arduino Uno [0001] to the virtual machine Dev VM.

USB device 'Arduino (www.arduino.cc) Arduino Uno'
with UUID {500b6ee9-e3c5-4dea-8f06-a8a863e75c0b} is busy with a previous request.
Please try again later.

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: HostUSBDeviceWrap
Interface: IHostUSBDevice {c19073dd-cc7b-431b-98b2-951fda8eab89}
Callee: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

What's even more interesting is that if I copy the virtual hdd to my Surface Pro 2 and try to attach the arduino in the vm there, it just does the thing without any issues. Even though it's the same version VBox with same version extension pack.

Host OS on desktop and surface is Windows 10 x64

is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's listed as an open issue with Oracle https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14275

I get exactly the same issue.  So far replicated this with version 5.0.6 and 5.0.10